# Datepicker with Nested Forms on Edit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, nested-forms

I am currently using the nested form gem by Ryan Bates https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form and implementing bootstrap-datepicker-rails https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails for one of my fields.

This work fine when adding a new record. The issue I am having is getting the datepicker to work when 'editing' the record with the nested form.

I have added the suggested javascript to my application to activate the datepicker when a new field (record) is wanting to be added

```
  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  // this field was just inserted into your form
  var field = event.field; 
  // it's a jQuery object already! Now you can find date input
  var dateField = field.find('.datepicker');
  // and activate datepicker on it
  dateField.datepicker(
{
        "format": 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        "autoclose": true,
        "placement": 'right'
    }
  );
  })
```

nested forms field block

```
  <%= f.fields_for :weeks do |week_form| %>
    <%= week_form.grouped_collection_select :product_id, @locations, :products, :name, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select Location" %>
    <%= week_form.text_field :start_at, class: 'datepicker' %>
    <%= week_form.text_field :end_at, class: 'datepicker' %>
    <%= week_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
    <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Week to Campaign", :weeks %></p>
```

Can anyone assist me in how I get this to work when editing the record as well?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Was able to achieve desired functionality with the following Coffee Script code:

```
jQuery ->

  $(document).on "nested:fieldAdded", (event) ->

  # this field was just inserted into your form
  field = event.field

  # it's a jQuery object already! Now you can find date input
  dateField = field.find(".datepicker")

  # and activate datepicker on it
  dateField.datepicker
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
  autoclose: true
  placement: "right"


  $(document).ready datepicker_update = ->
   $(".datepicker").datepicker
     dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     autoclose: true
     placement: "right"
```

Comment: Using this code I get an error; ReferenceError: event is not defined
 

field = event.field;